# Best datastructure in javascript for a certain relationship

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have already posted my question here:

[Best datastructure in javascript for certain relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63214104/best-datastructure-in-javascript-for-certain-relationship)

I try now to reformulate my problem and make it more clear.

Let us assume I have a table (for instance in an .csv file) with two columns and a few thousand rows. In the first column are arrays with 5 to 8 integers, eachs either 0, 1, 2 or 3. In the second I have an array of arrays containing two integers. It may look like

```
[3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2]      |   [[4, 50], [5, 50]]
[2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]   |   [[2, 50], [5, 100], [6, 50]]
.
.
.
[0, 2, 0, 0, 3]            |   [[0, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10]]
```

Now I want to load this table in javascript to store it such that, given for example the array `[2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]` , the retrieval of the array `[[2, 50], [5, 100], [6, 50]]` is very fast. Which is the best way / datastructure to store this table / relationship for a very fast retrieval?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The relationship between the input and output is as follows: For every zero in the input there is an array with two integers in the output, the first integer is the position of the zero. The second interger is a certain score for the input. The calculation of this score is a bit complex, but I think it is not of interest for this question. We can simply assume that this table is given.

Comment: what is `[2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]`?..

Comment: It is an array.

Comment: i was able to understand  that, i was asking for the relation with the output

Comment: assuming the first column is unique - wouldn't a regular old js object work?  basically a hashmap so good retrieve performance

Comment: I have added the relation in the Edit to the post, but I think it is not of interest for this question.

Comment: Yes, the first column is unique, but is it no problem when I have another array with the same content? Let's say arr1 = [2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1] and arr2 = [2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], however arr1 == arr2 is false (the array exists twice), would I get in both cases the output array?

Comment: You can use map with a custom hashing function. It should fill your use case probably most optimal. Very simple hashing function would be just joining the array. More complex one would be for example using bitwise operations.

Comment: "*The calculation of this score is a bit complex*" - if the second column can be **calculated** from the first column, it might be better (more memory-efficient, maybe even faster) to just run that calculation for an input instead of doing a lookup in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

While in theory it can use array objects as the key, it would compare them by identity, you probably are looking for lookup by value though. The simplest workaround for that is to use a string representation of the array as the key, e.g. `JSON.stringify(arr)` or `arr.join('|')`.

```js
const table = [
  [[3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2], [[4, 50], [5, 50]]],
  [[2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [[2, 50], [5, 100], [6, 50]]],
  [[0, 2, 0, 0, 3], [[0, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10]]],
];

const map = new Map(table.map(([key, val]) => [key.join('|'), val]));

console.log(map.get([0, 2, 0, 0, 3].join('|')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are effectively wanting to prioritise the retrieve of key/value pairs, a hash map should be the quickest solution. Plain js objects offer an in-built hashmap option (which is suitable as long as your keys are unique.

You should consider the js Map object if you wish to use Array objects (which may contain the same values) as keys.

e.g.

```
var arrayA = [1,2,3]
var arrayB = [1,2,3]
var map = new Map()
map2.set(arrayA, 'first')
map2.set(arrayB, 'second')
map2.get(arrayA) >> 'first'
map2.get(arrayB) >> 'second'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let us assume that I have two arrays, arr1 = [2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1] and arr2 = [2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], but arr1 != arr2 (so that the array exists twice in memory and the "pointers" arr1 and arr2 are different). Would I get in both cases the output array when calling map.get(arr1) or map.get(arr2)?

Comment: when you set the value for the key you will be passing a reference so it will still point to the original object. Can you clarify which column is the key and which is the value?

Comment: The first column is the key, the second the value. My question is, when I exchange the key array with another one but which has the same content, will I still get the value from the map?

Comment: Yes if you use map, the key will be the original underlying array rather than the value. If you use object I believe it will be translated into a string. So for this use case use map

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: have added an example of using map to store two different values against arrays with matching contents (but referencing different underlying objects)